# JavaScript not formatting in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

A few days ago some of my files stopped being formatted with spaces, indents, etc.

For example, right now my reducer is working (even with a flow error in the `customerWithReview` function:

#### reducer.js

```js
// @flow
import type {
  CustomerAction,
  CustomerState,
  CustomerCollection
} from "../CustomerTypes";

import Customer from "../../models/Customer";
import Review from "../../models/Review";

const logActionTypes = action =>
  action.type[0] !== "@" && console.log("CustomerReducer:", action.type);

const initialState: CustomerState = {
  customers: null,
  newItem: null,
  searchResults: null,
  error: null,
  isLoading: false
};

export default function customerReducer(
  state: CustomerState = initialState,
  action: CustomerAction
) {
  let customers: CustomerCollection;
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_CUSTOMERS_SUCCESS":
      return { ...state, customers: action.customers, isLoading: false };
    case "GET_CUSTOMERS_FAILURE":
      return { ...state, error: action.error, isLoading: false };
    case "NEW_CUSTOMER_START":
    case "CUSTOMER_ADD_REVIEW_START":
      return { ...state, newItem: null, error: null, isLoading: true };
    case "NEW_CUSTOMER_SUCCESS":
      customers = {
        ...state.customers,
        [action.customer.id]: action.customer
      };
      return {
        ...state,
        customers,
        newItem: action.customer,
        isLoading: false
      };
    case "CUSTOMER_SEARCH_SUCCESS":
      return { ...state, searchResults: action.results, isLoading: false };
    case "CUSTOMER_ADD_REVIEW_SUCCESS":
      const newCustomer = customerWithReview(action.review);
      customers = {
        ...state.customers,
        [action.review.customerId]: newCustomer
      };
      // debugger;
      return {
        ...state,
        customers,
        newItem: newCustomer,
        isLoading: false
      };
    case "NEW_CUSTOMER_FAILURE":
    case "CUSTOMER_SEARCH_FAILURE":
    case "CUSTOMER_ADD_REVIEW_FAILURE":
      console.log("from reducer:", action.error);
      return {
        ...state,
        newItem: null,
        error: action.error,
        isLoading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }

  function customerWithReview(review: Review): Customer {
    const id: number = review.customerId;
    const oldCustomer = state.customers[id];
    const newReviews = [review, ...oldCustomer.reviews];
    const newCustomer = new Customer({ ...oldCustomer, reviews: newReviews });
    return newCustomer;
  }
}
```

but this component file, which is by the way error-free isn't formatting. Note the spacing in the `formProps` property inside the `render` function.

#### CustomerScreen.js

```js
// @flow
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  KeyboardAvoidingView
} from "react-native";
import {
  ThemeProvider,
  Text,
  Divider,
  Rating,
  Button
} from "react-native-elements";
import Customer from "../models/Customer";
import Review from "../models/Review";
import User from "../models/User";
import ReviewView from "../subviews/ReviewView";
import ReviewsList from "../subviews/ReviewsList";
import NewReviewScreen from "./NewReviewScreen";
import { addNewReview } from "../redux/action-creators/customerActionCreators";
import * as Types from "../redux/CustomerTypes"

type Props = { customer: Customer,
  addNewReview: function, allCustomers: Types.CustomerCollection, user: User, isLoading: boolean, newReview: Review
 };
type State = { isReviewing: boolean, isLoading: boolean };

export class CustomerScreen extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = { isReviewing: false, isLoading: false };

  automate = async() => await setTimeout(this.startReview.bind(this), 10)

  // componentDidMount = () => this.automate()

  createReview({ content, rating }: Review) {
    const review = {
      customerId: this.props.customer.id, userId: this.props.user.id, content, rating,
      userId: 8
    }
    this.props.addNewReview(review);
    // this.setState({ isReviewing: false });
  }

  startReview = () => this.setState({ isReviewing: true })
  cancelReview = () => this.setState({ isReviewing: false })
  get showReview(): boolean { return this.state.isReviewing || !!this.props.newReview }

  render() {
    // const customer = this.props.customer // provided by container
    const customer = this.props.allCustomers[this.props.customer.id]
    const listProps = {customer, onStartReviewPress: this.startReview.bind(this)}
    const formProps = {                onCancel: this.cancelReview.bind(this),
                onSubmit:this.createReview.bind(this),
                isLoading:this.props.isLoading
}
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
          style={styles.container}
          enabled
          behavior="position"
        >
          <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}>
            <CustomerInfo customer={customer} />
            {!this.showReview ? (
              <Reviews {...listProps}/>
            ) : (
              <NewReviewScreen
                onCancel={this.cancelReview.bind(this)}
                onSubmit={this.createReview.bind(this)}
                isLoading={this.props.isLoading}
              />
            )}
            <Divider style={{ height: 100 }} />
          </ScrollView>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  ({ customerReducer, authReducer }) => ({
    allCustomers: customerReducer.customers,
    user: authReducer.user.user,
    isLoading: customerReducer.isLoading,
    newReview: customerReducer.newItem
  }),
  { addNewReview }
)(CustomerScreen);

const CustomerInfo = ({ customer }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text h1>{customer.name}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.detailText}>{customer.address}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.customerDescription}>{customer.description}</Text>
      {customer.reviews.length > 0 && (
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.detailText}>
            Rating ({customer.reviews.length} reviews):
          </Text>
          <Rating
            readonly
            startingValue={customer.averageRating}
            style={styles.rating}
            imageSize={20}
          />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

type ReviewsProps = {}

const Reviews = props => 
  <View style={{ width: "100%" }}>
    <ReviewsList
      customer={props.customer}
      onStartReviewPress={props.onStartReviewPress}
    />
  </View>

const styles = {
  scrollView: {
    margin: 20,
    marginBottom: 100,
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignItems: "flex-start",
  },
  container:{},
  divider: {
    backgroundColor: "black",
    height: 50
  },
  detailText: { paddingTop: 5 },
  customerDescription: { marginTop: 25, textAlign:"center" },
  rating: { padding: 5, alignItems: "flex-start" }
};

const theme = {
  Text: {
    style: { fontSize: 18 }
  }
};
```

As requested I'm adding my package and settings. I'm not removing the code because one file works and the other one doesn't, so I'd love an explanation of why that might happen.

#### package.json

```js
{
  "name": "QMGProzReviewsNative",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.17.0",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.3",
    "sugar": "^2.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.104.0",
    "flow-typed": "^2.6.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest-mock-axios": "^3.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.55.0",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
    "redux-saga-tester": "^1.0.468"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

#### settings.json (workplace)

```js
{
  "javascript.validate.enable": false,
  "prettier.eslintIntegration": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

#### user settings

```
{
  "window.zoomLevel": -1,
  "editor.fontSize": 14,
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "never",
  "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
  "git.confirmSync": false,
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorError.foreground": "#ff5100",
    "editorWarning.foreground": "#45bd0000",
    "editorInfo.foreground": "#00000000"
  },
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
  "editor.showFoldingControls": "always",
  "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    // "other": false
  },
  "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true,
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
  "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 15,
  "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
  "workbench.editor.showTabs": false,
  "terminal.integrated.macOptionClickForcesSelection": true,
  "markdown.preview.fontSize": 18,
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "html": "html",
    "erb": "html",
    "js": "javascript-react"
  },
  "editor.parameterHints.cycle": true,
  "editor.occurrencesHighlight": false,
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "editor.renderIndentGuides": false,
  "editor.detectIndentation": false,
  "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": true,
  "diffEditor.renderSideBySide": false,
  "zenMode.hideLineNumbers": false,
  "git.autofetch": true,
  "csv-preview.theme": "cerulean",
  "mocha.files.glob": "spec/**/*.js",
  "debug.toolBarLocation": "docked",
  "debug.inlineValues": true,
  "debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere": true,
  "sync.gist": "2836d619beeccd77b4fffb43ad0a3495",
  "debug.console.fontSize": 14,
  "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
  "editor.fontFamily": "Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace",
  "python.jediEnabled": false,
  "react-native.packager.port": 19005,
  "[javascriptreact]": {},
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "flow.useNPMPackagedFlow": true,
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "prettier.eslintIntegration": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation",
  "editor.suggest.localityBonus": true,
  "editor.suggest.shareSuggestSelections": true,
  "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
  "javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true,
  "workbench.activityBar.visible": false,
  "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
  "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue"
}
```

Comment: Formatting has nothing to do with your code, you need to remove the code and add: your `package,json`, your `settings.json` (of vscode)

Comment: Maybe you can add the currently used version and extensions installed and activated..

Comment: Recently I had the same issue (on windows, it happened every time I closed my laptop lid with VSC open) closing and reopening VSC helped temporarily. Uninstalling and reinstalling helped fix the issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: @DennisVash I've added the package and settings files.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl+k, Ctrl+F and use any code formatting extension like prettier.